# F# separating username from email

Tags: f#

I need to do function which will separate username from email. Variable name has username in it but i have no idea how can i return it.

```
let rec email (a:string) =
        let rec loop i (name:string)=
            if a[i] <> '@' then loop (i+1) (name+a[i].ToString())
        loop 0 ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heres an implementation using built-ins

```ml
let email (a: string) = 
    a
    |> Seq.takeWhile (fun c -> c <> '@')
    |> Seq.toArray 
    |> System.String
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec email (a:string) =
    let rec loop i (name:string)=
        if a[i] <> '@' then loop (i+1) (name+a[i].ToString())
        else name
    loop 0 ""
```

Comment: this works? I've marked it up...the main thing is that it works...is this homework? I can try to guide you to a more elegant implementation, though 'elegant' is subjective.

Comment: Yeah it works, it's a sample task for the test. If you can show me better implementation that would be amazing

Comment: sounds like that would be cheating though if its a test.

Comment: there are loosely 2 simple styles of recursive function like this, 1, uses a parameter you pass in to construct the final answer...which is what u have done, the other simpler model constructs the answer directly from the recursive call without the need for this extra parameter. One version is simpler, the other slightly more powerful. I think you can use the simpler method, get rid of 'i', and process the string as a list of chars, for me that would be slightly more elegant (simpler). If i write it, it would be cheating...the MAIN thing is you have written something that is correct.

Comment: I'm assuming the test is on functional programming, not 'fancy' techniques, so for me your answer is a better demonstration than piping takeWhile into ToArray